# Android: are there any good solutions how to validate Editboxes

Tags: android, validation

For example, I want to **Validate Minimum-Length**, and if it's `Email`, a `PhoneNumber`.

How is this possible in android. I want to validate.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you wan to prevent user to type something, then extend the `InputFilter` and register it with your `EditText`.

   ```
   // built in InputFilter.LengthFilter limits the umber of chars
   EditText.setFilters(new Filter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(100)})
   ```

Comment: I need to validate, email, and set minmumlength.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things that you can do to validate

1. Add input filters. More on it is here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html How to add filter to editable view is mentioned here [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html#setFilters%28android.text.InputFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html#setFilters%28android.text.InputFilter%5b%5d%29)
2. Use TextWatchers to modify the content on the go. More on TextWatchers is here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html Set this up for your EditText using [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29)

Note: There are few of them implemented in Android itself. Make use of them if you can. Look for subclasses in the documentation for TextWatcher and InputFilter

Answer (score 1):

For the validation of Text box

**1. minimum length:** u can directly give the length of that text.
 **2. mail validation:**

```
public boolean isEmailValid(String email)
        {
             String regExpn =
                 "^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@"
                     +"((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
                       +"[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\."
                       +"([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
                       +"[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
                       +"([a-zA-Z]+[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$";

         CharSequence inputStr = email;

         pattern = Pattern.compile(regExpn,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
         matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);

         if(matcher.matches())
            return true;
         else
            return false;
 }
```

**1. For phone number:**  If you want to fix length then give the length and the input type is number.

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look here :) [Android: Validate an email address (and more) in EditText](http://www.andreabaccega.com/blog/2012/05/26/android-validate-an-email-inside-an-edittext-and-more/)