# How to implement a form with a holo style like the stock add contact app?

Tags: android

I need to collect user input, and I want to use the same style as the stock android "add contact app", like the screenshot above (can't post images still):

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/images/xcontact30.png.pagespeed.ic.rcgxciehCj.png

I know I can use the EditText widget but how I add the "Phone", "Email" widget? Are they edit text too? Can you give me some xml example?

**EDIT**: What I want to diplay is the "Phone" *label* (not the entry itself): I need the xml values to make it identical to the phone (font, style, type).

Thanks a lot

**EDIT 2 (SOLVED):**
I solved this thanks to user @divoom12 and this help [Android Drawing Separator/Divider Line in Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049852/android-drawing-separator-divider-line-in-layout)

```
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="1dp"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:text="CATEGORY"
            android:textColor="#33b5e5"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#33b5e5" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="@string/name"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they too are EditText. Every EditText can be set a property `android:inputType=""`. But you can make your own validation. For e-mail EditBox, check this thread: [Android Email EditText Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355899/android-email-edittext-validation). If you want to use the stock then you can do like this `android:inputType="textEmailAddress"`, and  for phone: `android:inputType="phone"`. There are a lot like this. Check them out here: http://www.androidpeople.com/android-edittext-inputtype . Please if this helps mark this as the answer. :)

**Edit:** If you want your app to be with holo theme, add this to your manifest, in the application tag: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"`

**Edit:** This is the textView:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="PHONE" 
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="21dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"

    android:textColor="#33b5e5"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom"/>
```

And here is the background, which makes it to look like the picture: (bottom.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#33b5e5"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:bottom="2dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Is this what you are looking for? It looks like on the picture to me (colors, bottom border etc.). If you need help, just ask. The color of your activity should be white, for best results. Hope this helps.

Comment: Look at the edit: I need the xml values to make an identical "Phone" label, not the input text itself. Just the blue one :)

Comment: Okay I changed my post. Its now a blue label, with blue border, and white background. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: It's amost done! The problem is that the bottom blue line is obtained using 2 rectangles. Any chance to have a line with transparent background?

Comment: What do you mean a line with a transparent background? The line to still be blue, but to be see through?

Comment: Yes, for example if I have a bitmap background, your actual code will show a white rectangle and a blue line. I don't want a white rectangle. Changing color to #00FFFFFF it will show the blue rectangle.This is the effect I need: http://s13.postimg.org/cklsdrh07/Capture.png

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know a way to do this. There is a way but it is very amateur and weird. Its working though. You remove the background, and under the textview, create a EditText, with layout_width="fill_parent" and layout_height="2dp" (maybe 3dp or 4dp). This will only work on holo theme, and the line will be always blue. Then you can modify the EditText, to be untouchable, if someone tries to click on it, just to be sure, and thats it. You have a blue bottom border. It is very amateur way but it is working. Hope this helps. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

- POSSIBLE INPUT TYPES

  none text

  textCapCharacters

  textCapWords

  textCapSentences

  textAutoCorrect

  textAutoComplete

  textMultiLine

  textImeMultiLine

  textNoSuggestions

  textUri

  textEmailAddress

  textEmailSubject

  textShortMessage

  textLongMessage

  textPersonName

  textPostalAddress

  textPassword

  textVisiblePassword

  textWebEditText

  textFilter

  textPhonetic

  textWebEmailAddress

  textWebPassword

  number

  numberSigned

  numberDecimal

  numberPassword

  phone

  datetime

  date

  time